# Create Drop Down Box in Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create a drop down box in rails and I'm getting an error and I'm hopping that someone can shed some light as to why.

Here is the error:

```
undefined method `bot_id' for #<Robot:0x007fa1d663cac0>
```

Robots class:

```
class Robot < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :color1, :color2, :image, :name, :speed, :weapon_damage, :weapon_slots, :bot_id
  ROBOT_TYPES = Hash.new("Mini Bot" => "1", "Micro Bot" => "2", "Macro Bot" => "3")
  ....
  end
```

Form:

```
...
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bot_id %><br />
    <%= f.select :bot_id, Robot::ROBOT_TYPES%>
  </div>
...
```

Comment: $ bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: I've done db:migrate, are you suggesting that I include the bundle exec?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

For this to work, you must pass the second arg as a special options_for_select.  There is a helper to convert your hash for you.

You should read:

[select_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)

[option_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

Try this:

```
<%= select_tag :bot_id, options_for_select(ROBOT_TYPES) %>
```